# readfile download a blank/empty file

Tags: php, download, readfile

I'm trying to use readfile to download a file from the server.

The file definitely exists and when I use the URL in browser directly it downloads the correct file as predicted.

However when I do it with the following code, it download the file with the correct filename but it is completely blank in content, and zero bytyes.

I am wondering if this code is in fact incorrect and it is instead creating a new file, which of course would be blank.

```
function downloadFile($filename){
    $downloadroot = 'http://my.url.co.uk/exports/'.$filename.'.csv';
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.csv');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    readfile("$downloadroot");
}
```

What would be the cause of this? Is there an alternative way to download files from a URL without having to create some sort of "save target as" link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use file_get_contents() see http://php.net/file_get_contents for the full details.

Or if it's only csv's you're trying to read:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php